# Problems printing to Xerox 6027 from Gnome Ubuntu

Tags: printing, ubuntu-gnome, xerox

I've been having problems printing from Gnome Ubuntu to a Xerox Workcentre 6027.  I've searched the forums and found things that sounded like they should work.  I've tried restarting cups, rebooting, shutting down the computer and restarting it 5 minutes later, restarting the printer, shutting down the printer and waiting 5 minutes.  Nothing seems to work.  Lastly I tried removing the printer and readding it through the printers control panel but I get a pop up that says "Failed to add new printer".  It was easy enough to remove the printer but now I can't readd the thing.

Comment: Please give details about why you can't re-add it. What you do and what happens.

Comment: I've added the exact error message and exactly how I got it in the question text.

Comment: What were those *things that sounded like they should work*? All you probably needed was drivers: http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6027/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en&contentId=131219&from=downloads&viewArchived=false

Comment: I tried sudo service cups restart and lprm sudo service cups restart.  Neither had any effect.  I have the driver downloaded direct from Xerox.  I have checked their site and there is no update.  To be clear, the driver used to work flawlessly, then it started not working and I'd have to restart the printer and/or the computer.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the driver?

Comment: I have not.  I have the same driver installed that is listed on the website.  I do not know which packages to purge to get rid of the driver from the system.  Also, little scared to go putzing around as the articles I've read online imply that could have very severe consequences.

Comment: I just used Synaptic to remove the printer driver.  I then reinstalled with a freshly downloaded driver from the link provided by CelticWarrior but I still get the same error.

Comment: When I was trying to reinstall the driver I was accidentally selecting to add the shared version of the printer (my other Ubuntu machine was sharing the printer and I didn't realize it).  I had to reset the wireless driver on the Xerox machine and I was able to install the new driver to the printer but I still can't print.  I'm going to try rebooting and hopefully that will fix the problem.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the printer on a Windows computer and another Ubuntu machine it seems the problem is with the router and not the computers or the printer.